# Db:migrate produces no error and does not create table in database (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, dbmigrate

I'have created model using **rails generate model users**.i have created new data base readit_development and granted all privileges on this database to user readitadmin. In **my database.yml** file i have given user name as **readitadmin** and password as "**password**" and adapter **mysql2**. after **rake db:schema:dump** command file **db/migrate/20160914144019_create_users.rb**  was created. after db:migrate command i can not find table users in the database. i didn't get any error after db:migrate command. what could be the problem? i am naive to ruby on rails.

Comment: Did you added any fields inside your user model?

Comment: could it be possible that this is not the first time you run that migration ?, look in your `schema_migrations` table, and look for `20160914144019`, delete it if it's there.

Comment: @fantaI have deleted migration and drop table from database and destroyed model. Again created all those. Problem remain. Yes i have added  t.String "email", :limit=> 50 AND t.colum,:string, :limit=» 50,:null=» false Field

Comment: I have UP method with create_table specified and DOWN method with drop_table spefied in same migration. Is it possible that while i rake db:migrate both cancle each other and i am left with no table in database??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My model name was "users". Which is plural.  But when i destroyed my model and created new model "user"  then added some fields,  db:migrate worked and created table for me in database. i don't what is wrong with plural model name.